# url not opening next page - django/python

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-views

When I try to select a button I have inputed, I am hoping it will take me to the "completed_event" url. However, it only displays the "next url" which is the current page it is already on. In other words, it refreshes the page, but does not open the next url I have setup.

Could someone please help me with the redirect?

Thank you!

urls.py:

```
url(r'^event/completed/(?P<calendar_slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<event_id>\d+)/$',
    'schedule.views.completed_event',
    name='completed_event'),
```

views.py:

```
def completed_event(request, calendar_slug, event_id=None, next=None, form_class=EventForm):
    instance = None
    if event_id is not None:
        instance = get_object_or_404(Event, id=event_id)

    calendar = get_object_or_404(Calendar, slug=calendar_slug)

    next = get_next_url(request, next)
    context = {
        'next': next,
        'calendar': calendar,
    }
    return render(request, 'schedule/completed_event.html', context)
```

html file:

```
{% if user.is_staff %}
    <a href="#" onclick="openURL('{{completed_event}}?next={{here}}', event);">
        <img border="0" src="{% static "schedule/img/completed.png" %}" alt="{% trans "Event Completed" %}">
    </a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: If in the request you pass a url next attribute, do you want to redirect users to that url ?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just using the link as a link?

Answer (score 0):

You can use context variables between `{{` and `}}` and there is no context variable called `completed_event`. What you really want is the reverse resolution of a named URL. Instead of

```
<a href="#" onclick="openURL('{{completed_event}}?next={{here}}', event);">
```

try

```
<a href="#" onclick="openURL('{% url 'completed_event' %}?next={{ next }}', event);">
```

I also changed `here` to `next` because it looks like it is a typo; you don't have a context variable called `here` either.